# KSOAP webservice without using WSDL to send and Receive XML files on Android SDK

Tags: android

I am very new to android, I have to made an app which will use web services, which are made in .net.

SOAP and HTML can be used only, no WSDL is available.

I have to Send an XML an Receive an XML in Response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ksoap2 for android library
please see the  link http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar&can=2&q= 
It have the information about ksoap2,it may help you